Unable to Retrieve p-values in Google Earth Engine for Kendall's Correlation Analysis
This question has been asked previously: Significant Mann Kendall Tau.
I am using the ee.Reducer.kendallsCorrelation function within Google Earth Engine's JavaScript API to compute  the Kendall's Tau-b rank correlation for each pixel across an Image Collection temporal series.
// Define the point where the reducer's data is sampled
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Point([-1.0495, 41.871]);

// Filter Landsat images and get only one band per image
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('2021-03-01', '2021-06-01').filterBounds(aoi)
    .map(function(img){return img.select('SR_B.*')});

// Compute the reduction
var kendall = dataset.reduce(ee.Reducer.kendallsCorrelation());

While the TAU coefficient is correctly returned, the attempt to sample the p-value yields an empty feature collection.
// Select tau values
var tau_values = kendall.select('.*_tau').sample(aoi).first();
print(tau_values.toDictionary());

// Select p-values
var p_values = kendall.select('.*_p-value').sample(aoi);
print(p_values);

The reduceRegion function returns a null p-value.
var p_value_max = kendall.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 30
});
print(p_value_max);

Why am I obtaining a null p-value?
Could it be due to an insufficient number of pixels to compute the Kendall's coefficient?
